# Nginx infinite redirect, reverse proxy with docker-compose

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, lets-encrypt

I am trying to redirect HTTP requests to HTTPS, but keep on hitting an infinite redirect with nginx.

I've tried:

- Appending/removing the trailing slash from the nginx `proxy_pass` value
- Removing/keeping `proxy_set_header  Host  $host;`
- Changing docker to serve on the host's port 8080 (instead of `80`), and updating the nginx conf accordingly. (This returns connection refused errors.)

It looks like the redirect process goes like:

1. Client hits port `80`
2. Client is redirected to port `443`
3. The `proxy_pass` location in the `443` location block hits port `80`
4. This new request is redirected to port `443`
5. Repeat ad infinitum

How do I stop this from looping?

Here's my `nginx.conf` file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name sub.mydomain.com;

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/certbot;
    }

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name sub.mydomain.com;
    server_tokens off;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub.mydomain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub.mydomain.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://sub.mydomain.com/;
        proxy_redirect      off;
   #     proxy_set_header    Host               $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;
        proxy_set_header    X-Url-Scheme        $scheme;
    }
}
```

(The `include`d `/etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf` file is auto-generated by Certbot.)

Here's my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./data/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
    command: "/bin/sh -c 'while :; do sleep 6h & wait $${!}; nginx -s reload; done & nginx'"
    depends_on:
      - certbot

  certbot:
    image: certbot/certbot
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
    entrypoint: "/bin/sh -c 'trap exit TERM; while :; do certbot renew; sleep 12h & wait $${!}; done;'"
```

The `docker-compose` and Let's Encrypt setup is based on [this repo](https://github.com/wmnnd/nginx-certbot)

Comment: What is the use of location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/certbot;
    }

Comment: And what should be the initial url that will be redirected to https?

Comment: The acme challenge files are just to verify certbot's connection between the domain and its IP ([see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41803140/certbot-well-known-acme-challenge))

Comment: All http urls should be redirected to their https equivalent. The only thing that should change is the scheme.

Comment: It will definitely got into infinite loop.. as you are moving from http →https → http (on same domain name). What is the need of going back to http with same sub domain name as of initial url?

Comment: @Parul I don't want to move back to http; I want to remain on https. However, docker is serving the website on port 80, so that's where I have proxy_pass pointing.

Comment: Due to this line, proxy_pass  http://sub.mydomain.com/ in SSL enabled server node in nginx configuration , nginx will execute first server node again because of the server_name mentioned there.

Comment: Right, I understand that @Parul...I'm wondering how I can serve the site without hitting the redirect loop. Removing that line would stop the redirect loop, but wouldn't serve the site.