# infinite loop when setting up reverse proxy with docker and nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm setting up the reverse proxy with Docker and Nginx.

I used the page `https://example.org/` for an example.

1. I set up the custom domain with local mapping in `/etc/hosts`
   `127.0.0.1 example.org`
2. I set up the docker-compose file as below

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: nginx-reverse-proxy
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./nginx-selfsigned.crt:/etc/nginx/nginx-selfsigned.crt
      - ./nginx-selfsigned.key:/etc/nginx/nginx-selfsigned.key
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
```

3. Then I set up the `nginx.conf`

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    server {
       listen 80 default_server;
       listen 443 ssl;
       ssl_certificate nginx-selfsigned.crt;
       ssl_certificate_key nginx-selfsigned.key;
       server_name example.org;
       add_header Last-Modified $date_gmt;
       proxy_cache_bypass 1;

       location / {
           add_header  X-Upstream  'default docker' always;
           proxy_pass https://example.org;
           proxy_ssl_server_name on;
       }
    }

    include servers/*;
}
```

But after I run `docker compose up`

Then I access the page `https://example.org`

I got `502 bad gateway` error with a lot of headers `X-Upstream: default docker` added which I configured

I don't know which one is wrong in the configuration :(
[image]

UPDATED:

I'm not finding out the issue yet.

I decided to go with `proxy_pass https://ip_address` rather than with the domain name. I don't understand why it work with nginx on local machine but not with nginx in docker

Comment: What are you trying to do here?

If you just want 127.0.0.1 to redirect to example.org, you shouldn't need that entry in /etc/hosts, because the reverse proxy will handle that redirect for you.

Comment: I'm trying to append more headers to the request. 
I did it with nginx (I installed via brew) without docker and it worked. And now I'm trying to do it with docker

Comment: The current config worked for me, but I don't have that /etc/hosts entry. Maybe try removing it? Also, are you getting any errors in your nginx logs?

Comment: yahh. i think the problem is at `proxy_pass https://example.org` however if I dont set it in /etc/hosts, the request will never come to nginx. I updated `proxy_pass https://google.com` it redirects to this page successfully

Comment: I think I got the same issue here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63307831/nginx-infinite-redirect-reverse-proxy-with-docker-compose

Comment: I think you have an infinite loop of redirecting from 127.0.0.1 -> example.org -> 127.0.0.1 -> example.org... I tried setting up a similar route with "proxy_pass http://localhost" and also got a 502 gateway error because of this infinite loop. The nginx logs were overflowing with 502 errors. But unlike that link, I believe your loop is because you have example.org redirect to 127.0.0.1 in your /etc/hosts. Could you make requests localhost, instead of example.org?